# How can I speed up array generations in python?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, performance, opencv

I'm thinking I need to use numpy or some other library to fill these arrays fast enough but I don't know much about it. Right now this operation takes about 1 second on a quad-core Intel PC, but I need it to be as fast as possible. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
import cv

class TestClass:

  def __init__(self):

    w = 960
    h = 540

    self.offx = cv.CreateMat(h, w, cv.CV_32FC1)
    self.offy = cv.CreateMat(h, w, cv.CV_32FC1)

    for y in range(h):
      for x in range(w):
        self.offx[y,x] = x
        self.offy[y,x] = y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're generating a half million integers and creating over a million references while you're at it. I'd just be happy it only takes 1 second.

If you're doing this a lot, you should think about ways to cache the results.

Also, being on a quad-core anything doesn't help in a case like this, you're performing a serial operation that can only execute on one core at a time (and even if you threaded it, CPython can only be executing one pure-Python thread at a time due to the Global Interpreter Lock).

Comment: Why is this marked as a solution?  It doesn't answer the question at all, and it's misleading at best--creating a million integers and a million references doesn't take anything close to a second in Python (on a typical PC).

Answer (score 8):

My eight year old (slow) computer is able to create a list of lists the same size as your matrix in 127 milliseconds.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\gdk\Desktop>python -m timeit "[[x for x in range(960)]
 for y in range(540)]"
10 loops, best of 3: 127 msec per loop
```

I don't know what the cv module is and how it creates matrices. But maybe this is the cause of the slow code.

Numpy may be faster. Creating an array of (python `int`) 1s:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\gdk\Desktop>python -m timeit -s "from numpy import one
s" "ones((960, 540), int)"
100 loops, best of 3: 6.54 msec per loop
```

You can compare the timings for creating matrices using different modules to see if there is a benefit to changing: [timeit module](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html#module-timeit)

Comment: Although your answer addresses the time problem, it doesn't do exactly what the code in the original question do. Thus, your comparison is bias.

Also, the two codes you posted do different things so the comparison is unfair.

Comment: Of course my code isn't the same as the question's. And neither do I say that the OP should use my code. The examples I provide are to show how you can time different methods for creating large matrix-like objects. My final sentence tells the OP to time the different methods so he can decide if there is a benifit to changing - he shouldn't make a change until he has evidence that another method is quicker or more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

The code in Numpy that does exactly what you did in OpenCV python is

```
import numpy as np
offsetx, offsety = np.meshgrid(range(960),range(540))
```

If you are using Python, consider learning the different functions of numpy will help you tremendously. OpenCV functions can work directly with numpy arrays as well. The syntax of numpy in Python is much better than OpenCV though.

Here is are the times of the two versions in my i7

```
time python test.py

real    0m0.654s 
user    0m0.640s
sys 0m0.010s
```

My version:

```
time python test2.py

real    0m0.075s
user    0m0.060s
sys 0m0.020s
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the same matrix over and over, it may be faster to initialise it using `cv.SetData()`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can atleast use xrange instead of range. range creates an entire list of all those numbers. xrange generates them 1 by 1. Since you're only using them one at a time, you don't need a list of them.

Comment: I think, that modern Python interpreter changes "for range(...)" to "for xrange(...)" automatically. So it is optimization only in theory or some simple (less intelligent) interpreters.

Comment: In Python 2.x (including the just released 2.7), the `range` built-in still returns a list, so using `xrange` is an optimization.  In Python 3, `range` returns a `range` object, an iterable object similar to what `xrange` returns in Python 2.

Comment: My timings in Python 2.6.1 show range taking `4.70` seconds and xrange taking `2.29`. The code I used was `for i in range(1000000): pass` and the same for xrange. Used timeit with number=100.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully understand what you were trying to achieve. But here are two concrete examples and benchmarks which might help you. They both do the same thing, fill 960x540 image(array) with red.

**slow.py uses for loops to fill array**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

width, height = 960, 540
image = np.zeros((height, width, 3), np.uint8)
# Fill array with red
for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        image[y, x] = (0, 0, 255)

cv2.imwrite('red.jpg', image)
```

*Running time*

```
$ time python slow.py
real    0m2.240s
user    0m2.172s
sys 0m0.040s
```

**fast.py uses numpy to fill array**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

width, height = 960, 540    
image = np.zeros((height, width, 3), np.uint8)
# Fill array with red
image[:] = (0, 0, 255)
cv2.imwrite('red.jpg', image)
```

*Running time*

```
$ time python fast.py
real    0m0.134s
user    0m0.084s
sys 0m0.024s
```

**Using numpy instead of for loops is almost 17x faster**